# how should I ask a barber for a bald haircut

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

I want to ask my barber to make my hair bald. Which one is correct?

1. I want to go bald
2. Bald haircut

by bald, I dont mean completely bald. I want to keep little bit of hair. would this be fine "take it all off, close to very short"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither! Going bald refers only to the natural loss of hair (although your barber would certainly understand you).

Say "take it all off, leave nothing." Or "I want a buzz cut."

Comment: by bald, I dont mean completely bald. I want to keep little bit of hair. would this be fine "take it all off, close to very short"

Comment: no -- "take it all off" means get rid of all the hair. Hmm... say, "I want it very short, with clippers, no more than 2 millimeter clippers."

Comment: @hunter It sounds like you want a "number 2, all over", the barber will know what you mean, more info on the numbering system here - http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/15984/16657

Comment: In the specific case of wanting your hair almost completely gone, I would probably say, "I want a wiffle."

Answer (score 4):

I would call that a **shaved head**. You might request this as

> I would like my head shaved, please.

The barber would cut off as much hair as possible with clippers, and then use a razor to shave off the remaining stubble. You will then have only the smooth skin on top of your head, but you need to maintain it regularly.

Then, you will *appear* to be bald, but you will not *actually* be bald. Baldness is a state in which you cannot grow hair, while choosing to remove all your hair is called shaving your head.

Answer (score 1):

I said, "Take it all off and razor shave me smooth". My lady barber did just that. She used the clippers to bulk cut my hair to a stubble,  then razor shaved my head totally smooth.

Comment: Please refrain from including details that don't answer the question. Also, even though OP's specific examples were addressed in other answers, please address them in your answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

When I asked my barber to ' take it all off ' he shrugged ran the bare clippers ( No guard) from forehead to crown three times then said ' short enough, or do you want The razor? '

Answer (score 0):

In the UK (and I think in America too), very short haircuts are done with clippers. And you specify the length by a number.

"Number one" is a very short cut, 1/8 of an inch long (3mm) with scalp clearly visible.  If you want to have all your hair cut off, but not go completely bald you would ask for "A number one, all over please".  Expect the barber to check a couple of times to make sure this is what you really want, especially if your hair is longer.

Longer clipped cuts are also possible, up to number 8 (one inch or 25mm). And you can ask for "Number 5 on top and number 2 on the sides" for example. A "Number 0" would be without any guard, or about 1/16 of an inch (1-2 mm)

[Mens haircuts](https://www.menshairstylestoday.com/haircut-numbers/) gives examples of the appearance of the various cuts